# Add values of a function to listbox when click on checkbox?

Tags: c#

I have two checkboxes and one listbox. I assign functions to
both checkboxes. I want to add the items when I click on
checkboxes. I'm working on C#. I tried the following code.
It's working but overwrites the value when I click on
another check box.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        pizza();

    if (CheckBox2.Checked)
        burger();
}

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        pizza();
}

protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox2.Checked)
        burger();
}
```

Comment: Some more info on what you're trying to achieve would be helpful. Specifically language you're working in and perhaps an example of what you've tried to do so far.

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: @Pauk - they've already specified the language in the tag. ;)

Comment: @Luficer - If you look at the date of my comment and the history / edits of the post you'll see when I commented that wasn't in the tags :P

Comment: What the? July 11? I'm sorry Pauk. :(

Comment: @Tommy - No probs, I'll let you off :).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add data from a method to a listbox when the checked state of some checkboxes changes?  You will need the appropriate wire-ups in InitializeComponent, but that can be done through the designer.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(DataGenerator1());
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(DataGenerator2());
        }

        private DateTime DataGenerator1()
        {
            // this is just a sample, put what you want here.
            return DateTime.Now;
        }

        private DateTime DataGenerator2()
        {
            // this is just a sample, put what you want here.
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified any thing about language or technologies you are using, I'm taking liberty to assume that you want to accomplish things in HTML/JavaScript. So here is the solution.

```
    <input onchange="javascript:chkchanged('chk1');" type="checkbox" 
                                      id="chk1" value="chk1" /> Chk1<br/>
    <input onchange="javascript:chkchanged('chk2');" type="checkbox" 
                                      id="chk2" value="chk2" /> Chk2<br/>
    <select id="sel"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chkchanged(a)
    {
      if(document.getElementById(a).checked)
      {
            var s=document.getElementById("sel");
            var o = document.createElement('option');
            o.text = a;
            o.value = a;

            try {
                s.add(o, null);
            }
            catch(ex) {
                s.add(o);
            }
      }
      else //if you want to remove also on unchecking
      {
           var s=document.getElementById('sel');
           var i;
           for( i=0; i < s.length; i++ ) {
               if (s.options[i].text == a) {
                  s.remove(i);
               }
           }
      }
    }
    </script>
```